# Evitar que boton html envie formulario

Tags: html, formularios, botón

Tengo dos botones dentro de un formulario. Estos botones deben abrir una ventana modal para poder cargar `clientes` o `ingredientes` en una base de datos. Antes de los dos botones hay un `input` para nombrar un menu (el formulario es para crear un nuevo menu) y un `select` para elegir un cliente.

Este es el código de mis botones:

```
 <span class="input-group-prepend d-none d-sm-block">
       <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs ml-1 rounded" data-toggle="modal" 
        data-target="#modalAgregarCliente">Crear Cliente</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs ml-1 rounded" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modalAgregarIngrediente">Crear Ingrediente</button>
 </span>
```

El problema es el siguiente: Si yo no completo nada en el `input` o en el `select`, y doy click en alguno de los botones, sale la alerta diciendo que el `input` o el `select` (depende cual deje vacio) son un campo requerido (ya que tienen el atributo `required true`) y se muestra el modal (cualquiera de los dos) y todo funciona "correctamente".

Pero si en cambio, yo completo el `input` y escojo una opcion del `select`, no se abre el modal, directamente se envia el formulario, cosa que todavia no quiero.

Habra alguna propiedad para darle a los botones `Crear cliente` y `Crear ingrediente`, de manera tal que no envie el formulario?

> Al final del form, antes de la etiqueta de cierre, tengo un boton `submit`, yo quiero que este sea el unico boton que envie el formulario.

```
<div class="card-footer">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg float-right botonGuardar">Guardar Menú</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya lo solucione, agregando la propiedad ``type=button`` en cada uno de los botones que abren modales. Si quieren ponganlo en la respuesta asi lo cierro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El autor de la pregunta encontró por si mismo la solución. La respuesta estaba en agregar 'type=button' a los botones que abren los 'modals':

```
   <span class="input-group-prepend d-none d-sm-block">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs ml-1 rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCliente">Crear Cliente</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs ml-1 rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarIngrediente">Crear Ingrediente</button>
   </span>
```

Esto se debe a que los atributos 'submit' y 'button' se comportan del siguiente modo:

**Submit: el botón envía los datos del formulario al servidor.**

**Button: el botón no tiene un comportamiento predeterminado, lo que hace que se prevenga por tanto un comportamiento por defecto.**

Está respuesta se da a petición del autor de la pregunta para poder cerrarla.

Comment: Pero... ¿en qué radica la diferencia de usar o no button?

Comment: He corregido la respuesta con una breve explicación, es verdad que necesitaba aclaración. Contesté por la petición del autor y no aclaré el porqué. Gracias